# how to manage sessions in facebook android SDK 3.0 without using the UILifecycleHeler?

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-login

what is the right scenarios to handle Facebook SDK login without the UILifecycleHelper class.
and without using any fragments?

also

if I leave my app running for long time how to renew the session without user interaction?!

Comment: I dont know about that but i know that Android SDK 3.5 has been released please update you SDK...

Comment: Take a look into this library source code: https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook. `UILifecycleHelper` and fragments aren't used to handle login.

Answer (score 0):

issue solved, I found the Login Button flow on developers site very helpful,
thanks.